# Java Object compare with two fields for graphs

Tags: java, graph

I trying to merge a bunch of graphs into one. Keeping the vertices and then adding the edges one by one. I have an edge object and a graph object, made up of edges. An edge consists of u and v (weight but its nominal). In other words my graph G' would have all of Gi's nodes and consist of all edges that occur in every G0...Gn. I want to merge them an make one graph to BFS from source to destination later to simulate a changing wireless network. The code is java.

For example the 2 graphs A-B-C, A-C would become a A-B-C with a new path from A-C (I can't draw it).
to build(third parameter is nominal weight):

```
    Graph G1 = new Graph(2);
    G1.buildGraph(A,B,1);
    G1.buildGraph(B,C,1);


    Graph G2 = new Graph(3);
    G2.buildGraph(A,B,1);
    G2.buildGraph(A,C,1);
    G2.buildGraph(B,C,1);
```

Take the two above and create a third.

The problem is I can't repeat edges and I don't know how to set the object compare up for a hash or some efficient way of filtering out the repeated edges. I thought of looking for common sub-graphs between them which seem to me to be the same thing but that is NP complete.

I can post code if need be, I don't know how to hash using two fields in an object. I think I have to compare each u,v as a pair when creating the new graph to make sure I don't repeat the edge, I don't know how to do this other than comparing to them all which is an awful run time.

Thanks

Comment: Is the "can't repeat edges" a strict thing? or does it only have to be true in the end.  What I was wondering is if you couldn't add the edge and just increment the weight (all weights start at zero).  Then when you're done, just go through and turn any positive weight to one.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. You can combine two hashes, for instance, by doing `int combined = u + 31*v`. Multiplying with primes works well to evade collisions. If you wish to match edges, you'll likely want to match them by what vertices they connect. To match vertices (isomorphism problem) in subexponential time, you're going to need unique identifiers, like the A, B and C in your example, that match. Is that sort of thing feasible to construct?

Comment: If I repeat edges, I would think it would break a BFS search on the new graph. The thing is, I don't know how to combine the two hashes. I could do it the hard way and compare every edge added to every edge already in the graph but the time would be terrible.